# Pycaret Anomaly Plot_model

Tags: pycaret

I am using the anomaly module in Pycaret. It is an impressive program and easy to use.

`plot_model(knn, plot="umap", save=True)` engenders a nice umap plot, see pdf. This interactive plot identifies the *x=0* and *y=1* coordinates with hovering.

I would like to look at the *x=0* and *y=1* as primary data to manually cluster of groups. The df from 'assign' does not give this. only a single value 'score'.

Is there a way of identifying the *x=0* and *y=1* coordinates so that I can export them?

Thanks